# How can I access the innermost function of several nested functions?

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I can't seem to get the right syntax for this. I know how to access the function 1 level deep, but 2 levels isn't working for me.

```
var firstFn = (function() {
  var secondFn = (function() {
    function inner() {
      return "hi";
    }

    return {
      inner: function() {
        return inner();
      }
    }

  })();

  return {
    secondFn: function() {
      return secondFn();
    }
  };
})();

console.log(firstFn.secondFn.inner());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `secondFn` is actually a function object. So, you need to invoke it like this

```
console.log(firstFn.secondFn().inner());
```

**Note:** Your inner `secondFn()` returns an object, not a function. So, you need to change it like this

```
return {
  secondFn: function() {
    return secondFn;       // Note the absence of `()`
  }
};
```

---

**Note:** I strongly recommend using different names for your functions and objects, like this. So that it would be less confusing to understand what is happening.

```
var firstFn = (function() {
  var innerSecond = (function() {

    function innerFunction() {
      return "hi";
    }

    return {
      inner: function() {
        return innerFunction();
      }
    }

  })();

  return {
    secondFn: function() {
      return innerSecond;
    }
  };

})();
```

So, `firstFn` is an object which has a property called `secondFn`, which is a function.

When the `secondFn` is called, it returns another object called `innerSecond`, which has a property called `inner` whose value is function.

When you invoke `inner`, it actually invokes `innerFunction` and returns the result `hi`.

---

If you wanted to follow the same pattern as in `innerSecond`, then you need to return the function object as it is, instead of invoking it, like this

```
var first = (function() {

  var innerSecondFunction = function() {

    function innerFunction() {
      return "hi";
    }

    return {
      inner: function() {
        return innerFunction();
      }
    }

  };    // Note that we don't invoke the function object here

  return {
    secondFn: function() {
      return innerSecondFunction();   // but we invoke here
    }

  };

})();

console.log(first.secondFn().inner());
```